# Recursion schemes with mutually recursive types in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion-schemes

Given the following data types:

```scala
sealed trait Expression
final case class Add(a: Expression, b: Expression) extends Expression
final case class Block(statements: List[Statement], result: Expression) extends Expression
    
sealed trait Statement
final case class ExpressionStatement(expression: Expression) extends Statement
final case class Assignment(variable: String, expression: Expression) extends Statement
```

My first step was to do the following:

```scala
sealed trait ExpressionF[E, S]
final case class AddF[E, S](a: E, b: E) extends ExpressionF[E, S]
final case class BlockF[E, S](statements: List[S], result: E) extends ExpressionF[E, S]
    
sealed trait StatementF[E, S]
final case class ExpressionStatementF(expression: E) extends StatementF[E, S]
final case class Print(expression: E) extends StatementF[E, S]
```

But I am not sure how to use Fix with two type variables.

How can I represent these types so that I can use recursion schemes using droste or matryoshka/Fix?.

Answer (score 1):

I think in order to deal with mutually recursive types you need Indexed Functors. I'm not quite sure exactly how that works myself, but there's an example here – unfortunately it's in Haskell.

https://gist.github.com/cstrahan/eab72b39884ef37b7a3c125f77e99a2e

This library apparently implements recursion schemes for mutually recursive types, but again it's in Haskell and basically undocumented. But maybe it helps nevertheless....

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-ix

Comment: I dont understand haskell well enough to adapt the IFunctor typeclass and instances to scala, not sure if you woudl have any pointers?

Comment: I don't, unfortunately. I don't think anybody has done any work in that area in Scala.